# Loading Bitmap to ImageView from URL in android

Tags: android, url, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am using following method to retrieve a bitmap from the url and pass it on to the imageview , but the imageview is not being updated.

```
 public static Bitmap LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
         return null;
    }
```

call -

```
  mov1_poster.setImageBitmap(VPmovies.LoadImageFromWebOperations(mov_details[0][7]));
//doesn't work

  Toast.makeText(this,"url is \n"+mov_details[0][7],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // shows the url of the image successfully (just to check the url is not null)
```

Is there anything i am doing wrong ? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap image;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            image = null;
        }
        return image;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**Now call in your code:**

```
 new DownloadImageTask(YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW).execute("YOUR_URL");
```

Comment: Thanks , very helpful . Once i checked the log , found out NetworkOnMainThreadException was the reason , This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread . And for  this your answer was correct  , running the operation inside a separate(background) thread .

Answer (score 1):

Use [the picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) when working with images, it works wonders and it's easy!

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```