# Can't load an image from URL

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, imageview, android-imageview

I've tried to load an image from URLs but it's not working. Two different errors are happening. When I put an URL that starts with www the app doesn't close but neither load the image, only shows a white space. But when the URL start with http:// the app closes.

The code I'm using to load the image is the next:

```java
public class ThreadAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Threadx> data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ThreadAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Threadx> data) {
        super();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvSubject;
        TextView tvContent;
        ImageView imagen;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_thread, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvSubject = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvSubject);
            viewHolder.tvContent = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
            viewHolder.imagen = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String subject = data.get(position).getSubject();
        String content = data.get(position).getContent();
        String imagen = data.get(position).getImagen();
        viewHolder.tvSubject.setText(subject);
        viewHolder.tvContent.setText(content);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("www.matrallune.com/images/imagen_corporativa.jpg");
            //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("www.matrallune.com/images/imagen_corporativa.jpg").getContent());
            //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        viewHolder.imagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I tried different methods as you can see in the code but all of them have the same issues. My intention is to catch the URL from the variable "imagen".

Comment: you are missing      urlConnection.connect();

Comment: Does your app have the right permissions? Do you get an Exception?

Comment: You could also use the image loading library `Picasso` which can efficiently load the image and also can cache the response.  http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: And I would suggest to always add protocol at beginning of url.

Comment: @Krupal I tried but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @GB yes, I've already put the permissions in the manifest

Comment: @kamilmasta I tried with the protocol too but it didn't work,

Comment: @ShifarShifz I don't now how to use it, could you help me with some code for my example, please?

Comment: @ManelMendez so many people answered on how to use Picasso, i also answered one ;)

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this question >>
[Loading Bitmap to ImageView from URL in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176331/loading-bitmap-to-imageview-from-url-in-android/30176593#30176593)

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap image;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            image = null;
        }
        return image;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**Now call in your code:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        conv`enter code here`ertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_thread, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvSubject = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvSubject);
        viewHolder.tvContent = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        viewHolder.imagen = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    String subject = data.get(position).getSubject();
    String content = data.get(position).getContent();
    String imagen = data.get(position).getImagen();
    viewHolder.tvSubject.setText(subject);
    viewHolder.tvContent.setText(content);
    new DownloadImageTask(viewHolder.imagen).execute("www.matrallune.com/images/imagen_corporativa.jpg");
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Wow, It works! It's because of the AsyncTask? Thank you for the help!

Comment: And you can't update UI in worker thread. So asynt task is great to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are missing `urlConnection.connect();`
Change your code to:

```
    try {
            URL url = new URL("www.matrallune.com/images/imagen_corporativa.jpg");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Not sure though.

and as suggested in comments, it is wise to use library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It is very easy. just integrate and change code to:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imgView);
```

**update**: try including
 `connection.setDoInput(true); 
setUseCaches(false)`.

Comment: @ManelMendez ok, I was just guessing though..there may be other issues as well.

Comment: the same result always

Answer (score 1):

Loading Image through Picasso is just like saying 123, You are done

```
Picasso
.with(context) //Context 
.load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png") //Can be Url,File..
.into(imageView)//The ImageView;
```

This is just the normal loading,you could find more options in their [Documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

**According to your code**

```
Picasso
    .with(context) //Context 
    .load("http://matrallune.com/images/imagen_corporativa.jpg") //Can be Url,File..
    .into(viewHolder.imagen)//The ImageView;
```

you just wanted to replace the imageloading codes with the above code.

**Your Final Adapter**

```
public class ThreadAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Threadx> data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;

    public ThreadAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Threadx> data) {
        super();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvSubject;
        TextView tvContent;
        ImageView imagen;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_thread, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvSubject = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvSubject);
            viewHolder.tvContent = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
            viewHolder.imagen = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String subject = data.get(position).getSubject();
        String content = data.get(position).getContent();
        String imagen = data.get(position).getImagen();
        viewHolder.tvSubject.setText(subject);
        viewHolder.tvContent.setText(content);

        //Loading image
        Picasso
        .with(mContext) //Context 
        .load("http://matrallune.com/images/imagen_corporativa.jpg") //Can be Url,File..
        .into(viewHolder.imagen)//The ImageView;


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

If you are initializing the adapter from a Fragment, you should pass the context as getActivity() or you could also initialize it in the `onAttach()` of the fragment.

If you are initializing the Adapter from an Activity. you just wanted to pass `this`.

**Initializing**

from Activity

```
ThreadAdapter tAdapter = new ThreadAdapter(this,data);
```

from Fragement

```
ThreadAdapter tAdapter = new ThreadAdapter(getActivity(),data);
```

Comment: @ManelMendez updated answer with your final adapter. and that contains A-Z. ask me if you need more clarification.

Comment: the app stops when I try the code (when I put the attribute context. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Show me what's Logcat saying.

Comment: Look: 

05-13 19:12:20.285  10989-10989/api.dat.dsaqp1415gm2.dsa.eetac.upc.edu.dat_android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: api.dat.dsaqp1415gm2.dsa.eetac.upc.edu.dat_android, PID: 10989
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.

Comment: Ok, fine. The problem is that you passed an null Context. may i see how you initialized the Adapter object?

Comment: Like this: ThreadAdapter tAdapter = new ThreadAdapter(getActivity(),data); in a fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77742/discussion-between-shifar-shifz-and-manel-mendez).

Answer (score 0):

Using Picaso Lib http://square.github.io/picasso/ call `Picasso.with(context).load("http://imageUrl/image.png").into(imageView);`

Comment: Bit late @ManelMendez but it needed to be mContext

Comment: Let's try ClassName.this